# if statement with NAs and assigning a new column by using other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame(df) which includes NA's and numeric values. A sample of df is like:

```
col1 col2
8145 NA
8078 8156
NA   NA
8223 NA
8112 8003
```

Namely

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c(8145,8078,NA,8223,8112), col2=c(NA,8156,NA,NA,8003))
```

Desired output is:

```
col1 col2 col3
8145 NA   8145
8078 8156 8156
NA   NA   NA
8223 NA   8223
8112 8003 8003
```

Namely,

- if col2 is NA assign col1's value to col3;
- if col2 is not NA, assign col2's value to col3;
- if both col1 and col2 are NA, assign NA to col3.

I am new in R. I know that is a very easy problem but I couldn't handle it. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition is to replace elements based on `NA` values in "col2"

```
 indx <- is.na(df$col2)
 df$col3 <- ifelse(indx, df$col1, df$col2)
 df
 #  col1 col2 col3
 #1 8145   NA 8145
 #2 8078 8156 8156
 #3   NA   NA   NA
 #4 8223   NA 8223
 #5 8112 8003 8003
```

Or

```
df$col3 <- df$col2
df$col3[indx] <- df$col1[indx]
```

Or you can use row/col indexing

```
df$col3 <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), (!is.na(df$col2))+1)]
```